# Was Star Wars' Coruscant inpired by Isaac Asimov's Trantor?

Tags: star-wars, inspiration, isaac-asimov

They are both the Capitol of their respective Galactic Empire.

Both Star Wars and Foundation trilogy have masters of the mind arts, Jedi and Psycohistorians.

Comment: Trantor is, of course, entirely subterranean whereas Coruscant is build over the surface of the planet.

Comment: Coruscant is discussed in the dupe question.

Comment: The occurrences of Trantor / Coruscant in the answers of the supposed dupe are only unreferenced acknowledgements of their similarity by the answerers, there is only a single one-liner answer that references a source to Wikipedia, which itself doesn't offer any sufficient, IMHO, external sources, acknowledging similarities only. The other question also has a broader scope, and a possible inspiration of the whole Star Wars to the whole Foundation doesn't automatically imply an inspiration of Coruscant to Trantor, or vice-versa. For these reasons, I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Any answer to this one would be immediately duplicated into the wider question.

Comment: @Sekhemty We close specific to broad, this question is a subset of the other linked duplicate. If an answer would be found to this it should also be posted on the duplicate. Also poor and unreferenced answers has never been a reason to close or not to, provide a bounty if you must but that doesn't mean it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this makes sense. I had not thought of these considerations.