# When did the idea of Coruscant being a planet wide city develop?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, coruscant

Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/232857/75476) and the one it’s marked a duplicate of.

I distinctly remember a passage in the Timothy Zahn *Heir to the Empire* trilogy where a character looks out across to mountains on Coruscant, which makes me think those books pre-date the idea that it is a planet-wide urban sprawl.

What is the earliest reference to Coruscant being a planet-wide city?

Comment: Since all of Lucas' planets seem to be described by a single adjective, (desert planet, ice planet, swamp planet, ocean planet, cloud planet, volcano planet, etc) it only made sense to have a *city* planet as well

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach Notable exception being Naboo, which has *two* whole biomes - and of course each is populated by a different species so they may as well be separate planets.  And it somehow has liquid water at its core - Lucas wasn't big on geological plausibility.

Comment: It dates back to the 1940s: Coruscant was strongly inspired by the planet-spanning Trantor of Asimov's Galactic Empire.

Comment: Same time they decided an entire planet should be a desert and an entire moon could be forests ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Timothy Zahn's "Heir to the Empire" trilogy is the *first ever* mentioning of Coruscant, in 1991.  George Lucas later made the name official.

According to [The Making of Star Wars, J.W. Rinzler](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AKqMW5ChgScC&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn:9780091924997&pg=PP1&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), the idea of the Capital planet of the Galactic Empire being a single planet-wide city existed by the 1974 drafts of "The Star Wars", but at this points in time it was called **Alderaan**.  In the the 1975 draft *"Adventures of the Starkiller as taken from the Journal of the Whills, Saga I: The Star Wars"*, this had changed to a floating city in the clouds (which later became Cloud City, on the planet Bespin)

In early drafts of "Return of the Jedi", the city-planet cropped up again - this time, as the Emperor's homeworld, "Had Abaddon" (a name almost as ominous as "the Death Star"...) - but, was dropped due to a realisation that it would be too hard to show on screen.  Scenes set on Coruscant would, however, later be added to the 1997 Special Edition release - but without a name being given.

The first official mention in what is considered current-canon of Coruscant is then 1999's "Star Wars Episode 1: The Phantom Menace", where it is indeed a single city engulfing the planet.  This also changed the Emperor's homeworld from Coruscant to Naboo.

So, the idea of the Galactic Capital being a planet-sprawling city *existed* since before the first film, but was not *canon* until 8 years after "Heir to the Empire".  And, it certainly wasn't called "Coruscant" until Timothy Zahn named it.

Comment: Isn't it basically [Trantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Empire_(Isaac_Asimov)#Trantor)? Don't tell me Lucas didn't read Foundation.

Comment: Trantor was depicted as covered in domes and stretching underground, Coruscant is depicted as a normal city with above ground buildings, towers etc. Been quite a few years since I read the Foundation books but wasn't it a big deal that Trantorians never saw the sky?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer that is what is discussed in the question I linked to.

Comment: @Darren Excellent. Thanks..

Comment: @chx Well, it's never really described well. Let's hear it from the ENCYCLOPEDIA GALACTICA itself: 1/3 TRANTOR – ...At the beginning of the thirteenth millennium, this tendency reached its climax. As the center of the Imperial Government for unbroken hundreds of generations and located, as it was, toward the central regions of the Galaxy among the most densely populated and industrially advanced worlds of the system, it could scarcely help being the densest and richest clot of humanity the Race had ever seen.

Comment: More like Helior from Harry Harrison's *Bill, the Galactic Hero*.

Comment: 2/3 Its urbanization, progressing steadily, had finally reached the ultimate. All the land surface of Trantor, 75'000'000 square miles in extent, was a single city. The population, at its height, was well in excess of forty billions. This enormous population was devoted almost entirely to the administrative necessities of Empire, and found themselves all too few for the complications of the task. (It is to be remembered that the impossibility of proper administration of the Galactic Empire under the uninspired leadership of the later Emperors was a considerable factor in the Fall.)

Comment: 3/3 Daily, fleets of ships in the tens of thousands brought the produce of twenty agricultural worlds to the dinner tables of Trantor....

Its dependence upon the outer worlds for food and, indeed, for all necessities of life, made Trantor increasingly vulnerable to conquest by siege. In the last millennium of the Empire, the monotonously numerous revolts made Emperor after Emperor conscious of this, and Imperial policy became little more than the protection of Trantor's delicate jugular vein....

ENCYCLOPEDIA GALACTICA

(In retrospect. it sounds like something from Gulliver's Travels.)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Seldon visits the surface of Trantor in Prelude to Foundation (chapters 21-24). It's basically uninhabitable; all the waste heat from the city creates constant severe winds.

Comment: @chx - As far as being a big deal that Trantorians never saw the sky, I do not recall that being mentioned for Trantor. I think you are mixing up the Foundation series with the novel "The Caves of Steel", about detective Elijah Bailey and set on Earth with domed mega-cities. Also the sequel novel "The Naked Sun" where Elijah goes to another world and has trouble due to his aversion to being outside.

Comment: Less than a page after the Encyclopedia Galactica quote given above (_Foundation_, part I, chapter 3), Gaal Dornick takes an elevator up to the surface and has a long conversation with Jerril about Trantorians' relationship with the surface and (obliquely) the psychohistorical implications of that.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It was a big deal, after all, Imperial Palace was the only undomed place, that was a huge privilege. To quote " it was then at its peak. Its land surface of 200 million square kilometers was entirely domed (except for the Imperial Palace area) and underlaid with an endless city that extended beneath the continental shelves." (Prelude to Foundation)

Comment: @Alice - Your comment does not address anything I disputed, which is how *important* Trantorians never seeing the sky was to the plot of the Foundation series. Mark Wood's information does indicate it was stronger than I remember (it has been a very long while since I last read it), but it still seems at best only to be a side point, not a central theme as in *The Caves of Steel* and *The Naked Sun*.

Answer (score 20):

In the annotated 20th anniversary edition of *Heir to the Empire*, Timothy Zahn (actually, in the annotations for the very scene you recall) describes the situation thusly:

> Before *Heir*, the Empire's capital was referred to as *Imperial Center*. My take on it was that the planet must have had a history previous to the Republic and Empire, and would have therefore had some other name.... I gave the planet the name *Coruscant*, which means "glittering".

-- annotation #5, page 17

> At the time, I knew that Coruscant was a planet-wide city, but I assumed that there would still be a few areas of wilderness (maybe called *parks* by the inhabitants)... Mountains, for one thing, would probably not be cost-effective to knock down.

-- annotation #7, page 18

So going into the writing of *Heir*, although the Imperial capital didn't have a "proper" name, it had been mentioned (as "Imperial Center") and established as a planet-wide city - a fact that, to Zahn at least, wasn't incompatible with the idea of a few sizeable areas of wilderness, particularly mountains that would be difficult to build over. What Zahn *doesn't* disclose here is what source actually described Imperial Center in this way.

[According to](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Coruscant/Legends#Coruscant_chosen_for_the_films) the fan wiki, at [Celebration III](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Celebration_III), Zahn attributed that description to one of the West End Games RPG sourcebooks, and said that the idea itself went back to Lucas (presumably to the early draft version of Alderaan, as mentioned in @Chronocidal's answer).

> Just to make it clear, I did not invent the planet... George Lucas had invented the planetwide city a long time ago. When I was starting the Thrawn Trilogy, they told me to coordinate with the West End Games source material, and they had it listed as the Imperial Planet

Zahn did certainly use the WEG books for background material (especially starships), which he points out many times in his annotations (first in #14 on page 10). And the mentioned-but-previously-unseen Imperial capital would be a prime place to set an RPG adventure or open up for groups who wanted to play their own. The books in question - I can't pin down which one specifically the description of Imperial Center first appeared in - were published beginning in 1987. So, unless the RPG books themselves took that detail from an earlier work, they would be the first *published* reference to the Imperial capital as a planet-wide city.

Comment: Thanks. I might have to change the accepted answer just because you’ve come up with an earlier work, which after all, is the question I asked.

Comment: @Darren An earlier published work, though it's (obviously) not earlier than Lucas's draft scripts. But, I thought it might shed some light on matters either way. (I was going to comment on Chronocidal's post but then it turned into several comments' worth of material so I figured it'd be easier to read this way.)

Comment: Of course, from depictions in "Attack of the Clones" and "The Clone Wars", it seems that mountains may *not* have been knocked down, but rather **built over**…  (For example, we get a scale of how built-up Coruscant is when we see Ahsoka Tano descending through a vertical thoroughfare to lower levels in Episode 5 of Season 7, "Gone with a Trace")

Comment: There was a similar descend down in the first 3 seasons, too (got to crosscheck episode descriptions since im not sure which one exactly, only thing that im sure on is it being in early seasons since i didn't get past season 3 so far @Chronocidal